# Symfony2 homepage different for authenticated users

Tags: symfony

How can I define my Symfony2 routes to show a different homepage for authenticated users and non-authenticated users? For example, I want to do something like this in my *routing.yml* file:

```
homepage_authenticated:
    path:     /
    defaults:
        _controller: AcmeBundle:Home:homeAuthenticated
    requirements:
        user: is_authenticated_remembered   # <--- this part here

homepage:
    path:     /
    defaults:
        _controller: AcmeBundle:Home:home
```

Now obviously this doesn't work because I just invented it, but I'm sure there must be a way to do this, but I can't find it. I have an idea [Expressions](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/expression/expressions.html) may be the solution to this somehow, but I can't find any examples of actually *using* them, anywhere.

Comment: Why just not check in controller if user is logged in, and display different page or even forward to another controller.

Answer (score 1):

As Malcom suggested in the comment, it is better to handle redirects/page-rendering based on user's authentication status in the controller.
The security context saves the role related data and the authentication status. You can redirect your users to different pages by checking
 `$this->get('security.context')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')` and `$this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_NAME')`.

**For example:**

```
public function homeAction()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        if ($this->get('security.context')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')) {

            //Path handling for authenticated users
            if ($this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('admin_homepage'));
            }

            if ($this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_USER')) {

                return $this->render('VenomCoreBundle:Default:home.html.twig', array(
                        'notifications' => $notifications,
                        'unApprovedCount' => $unApprovedCount,
                        'status' => $stats,
                ));
            }
        }
        //non authenticated users are redirected here
        return $this->render('VenomCoreBundle:Default:login.html.twig');
    }
```

Comment: Or, since my controllers all extend the Symfony `Controller`, I can just use `$this->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED')`. I knew that I could do this, but I'm not sure that the controller is where it belongs, especially as the signed-in "homepage" isn't so much as a homepage as it is "the application". Really, the two pages are completely unrelated, and so I wanted to make that separation clear.